# score reset tennis app

Tags: android

i'm making a tennis score app and i have 2 questions:

1. how can i reset the number of clicks, because if i click 5 times or more it doesn't work anymore.
2. how can i make one of the score show "advantage" after the scores are "40 - 40".

   ```
   public class tennis extends Activity {

   // Private member field to keep track of the count
   int Count = 0;


   /** Called when the activity is first created. */
   @Override
   public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
       super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
       setContentView(R.layout.main);

       //Left Counter//
       final TextView countTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.TextViewCount);
       final Button countButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.ButtonCount);

       countButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

           public void onClick(View v) {
               Count++;
               if (Count==1){
               countTextView.setText("15");}
               else
               if (Count== 2){
               countTextView.setText("30");}
               else
               if (Count==3){
               countTextView.setText("40");}
               else
               if (Count==4){
               countTextView.setText("A");}
               else {
               countTextView.setText("0");}
           };
       });
   }
   }
   ```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try using a getText() to see if there's an advantage, or just use more Count if/else stuff.

```
       public void onClick(View v) {
    CountA++;
    if (CountA==1){
    countATextView.setText("15");}
    else
    if (CountA== 2){
    countATextView.setText("30");}
    else
    if (CountA==3){
    countATextView.setText("40");}
    else
    if (CountA==4){
      //Checks if BScore was Advantage initially and if AScore is 40
      if (CountB==3 && ATextView.getText() =="40" && BTextView.getText() =="A")
      {
        countBTextView.setText("40");
        CountA--
      }
      //Else if BScore is not A, and AScore is 40, set AScore to A
      elseif(CountB==3 && BTextView.getText() !="A")
      {
        countATextView.setText("A");
        CountA--
      }
      //Otherwise just reset score
      else
      {
        countATextView.setText("0");
        CountA = 0;
      }
};
```

Comment: Now i'm struggling with the thing that if the score is **"A-40"** and the second player scores, i want the score to go to **40-40**. How do I do that?

Comment: Edited original answer in reply

Comment: it works but i want for example: if **P1** has **"A"** and **P2** has **"40"**. i want that if i hit the button of P2, P1 goes back to 40.

Comment: All you basically had to do was to set the other TextView instead of its own, then change it up a bit to check for conditions. Edited again.

Answer (score 0):

Two options on reseting number of clicks. Either check if Count > 5 and reset it to 0 at the end of the function or use mod 5. I'm not really sure how you're keeping track of score there, but you could check for 40-40 when you update the score and give advantage to the scoring player.

Comment: @HunterX86 this is some pretty basic Java stuff. Perhaps your best bet is to read over some Java tutorials online.